# padding not working on border-ed div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a circle border around a div with a background image. I want the background image to be as big as can be with a 10px padding between it and the border. This image transitions (scaled down) to 50px when user scrolls and the border is removed so it needs to remain a background image that takes up as much space as possible

css

```
.brand, .brand:visited, .brand:hover {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 height: 100px; width: 100px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 background: url('img/logo.png') no-repeat center center;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Everything works except for the padding. Not sure how to fix it. ALSO, I don't want the background image clipped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The background of an element applies to any padding...unless the background-clip property is changed.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.brand {
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-200-200-7.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.brand:hover {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand"></div>
```

**Alternative**: Use a wide border and a box-shadow for the outer "border".

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.brand {
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-200-200-7.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px red;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.brand:hover {
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want the image clipped though

Comment: Good answer Paulie, from here on the user can CUSTOMIZE it to there need.

Comment: Added an alternative option.

Comment: looks good thank you, seems like easiest answer, but would a transparent border work since it may appear overtop an image so the thick border color would show

Comment: You could try it but I think you might get an odd result.

Comment: crap, thats why I was hoping for padding to work, It needs to look like a border/outline with space in between

Comment: You can still use the first option just play with the background size.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a border added to the `.brand` class with an relative positioned `.brand` where the `:after` pseudo class is positioned absolute.
this is to create an cricle that goes outside the shape.

```css
.brand,
.brand:visited,
.brand:hover {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.brand:before {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  content: "";
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
body {
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand"></div>
```

Comment: Btw, you need to change `//border: 5px solid #fff;` to `/*border: 5px solid #fff;*/` as you can't use `//` with CSS.

Comment: Wel as that is technicaly true, any rules that are "wrong" are ingnored so adding // breaks the rule.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible to have an unclipped `background:` take account of `padding:`.

So... this is a little bit hacky, but you *can*:

1. Declare `box-sizing: border-box;`
2. Have a `border:` stand in for `padding:`; and then
3. Have a `box-shadow:` stand in for `border:`.

See example below:

```css
/* Your original styles */
.brand, .brand:visited, .brand:hover {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 height: 100px; width: 100px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 background: url('img/logo.png') no-repeat center center;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

/* A few extra styles just to make the background and border visible */
.brand, .brand:visited, .brand:hover {
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
 border: 1px solid rgb(255,0,0);
}

/* An alternative using border-box, and box-shadow */
.brand2, .brand2:visited, .brand2:hover {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 height: 122px; width: 122px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 background: url('img/logo.png') no-repeat center center;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
 border: 10px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 box-shadow:1px 1px rgb(255,0,0), 1px -1px rgb(255,0,0), -1px -1px rgb(255,0,0), -1px 1px rgb(255,0,0);
}

/* Lining everything up */
div[class^='brand'] {
float: left;
margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand"></div>
<div class="brand2"></div>
```

Comment: will that cut off the background image, I have it set so that it fills the div. So I get that it ignores the padding. I just need space between the edge of the background and the border

Comment: The circles in the example above have exactly the same radius. The first `content-box` circle is `50px` content-radius + `10px` padding + `1px` border (`61px`), the second `border-box` circle is `61px` radius (including `50px` content-radius, `10px` border & `1px` box-shadow). In  both cases, the content-radius is `50px`. So, if your background-image is `100px` x `100px`, nothing (except the corners) will be cut off, no.